# Paint Shop Pro 7: how to create a new palette from my image?

Tags: corel-paint-shop-pro

I have an image and from it I want to create a new palette. But PSP Help isn't much and doesn't much. The menu choice I want might say "from the selected image, create a new palette," but that choice doesn't exist.

How can I create a brand-new palette from the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about PSP x7 but in x8 if you downsample the image to say 16 colours, then click the HSL Map option in the Materials palette, it gives you the 16 colours, you can then dropper each one and add to a created palette.

Might take a bit of time if you downsample to 256 colours, though!

Answer (score 2):

Although this question ought to be migrated (it was at photo.stackexchange.com originally), I'll provide an answer here:

In order to create a pallette from an image, the image needs to have a color pallette to begin with -- you can't directly create a pallette from a full-color image. You'll first need to reduce the color depth to 8-bit (256 colors) or lower. You can fiddle around in the settings for the depth reduction, but I usually find optimized octree and nearest color give me something close to the original (with some posterization, of course). You might find that optimized median cut gives a better rendition for some pictures, but opting for dithering rarely gives you quite the pallette you want -- the target colors are often achieved by dithering rather than by direct rendering.

Once you have reduced the image from full-color to a palletted image, you should be able to save the pallette and use it on other images (the option should be available under the Image menu).

Comment: after the color depth is decreased (that's the step I was missing) to 256, then the 'save palette' choice becomes available under 'colors', which is just what I want. Too bad only 8-bit. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the colour depth is decreased. This process reduces the number of unique colours in the image to <= 256, each pixel is assigned a palette index rather than storing its own colour value; but each palette colour is still 24 bit (8 bits per RGB channel).

Comment: @E100: The reduction to a color set that can be described in 8 bits (the lookup address) is the reduction in depth we're talking about. You young uns might not remember it, but there was a time when 8 bits was all we had to work with (VGA), and introducing a different pallette would change the display adapter lookup table. In the 24-bit (and higher) world, you can display images with multiple pallettes on the same screen, but it hasn't always been that way. Try going to your display settings and reducing the color depth to 256 colors (if you can) to see the difference.

Comment: I realise all that (my first computer didn't do graphics let alone colour)  but my point was that they are still 24-bit colour values in the palette. I was wrong to say that the colour depth [of the image] was not reduced. But in this case the palette values are what's important, not what's left of the image.